# Symfony deploy on kubernetes - env issues

Tags: docker, symfony, kubernetes

I have an symfony application and three kubernetes clusters : dev, staging prod.

I'm using env files to set the environment. I build docker images with the right .env and deploy through kubectl. But as a matter facts, the value of APP_ENV isn't taken into account, even though the other params are (database connexion for example).

My staging env is set to "test" but composer still installs dev dependencies and logs go to /var/log/dev.log. In these log lines I also have an app_environment value which should be set to "test" according to the .env file. Still I find "local" instead.

What am I doing wrong ?

My staging .env file :

```
#  * .env                contains default values for the environment variables needed by the app
#  * .env.local          uncommitted file with local overrides
#  * .env.$APP_ENV       committed environment-specific defaults
#  * .env.$APP_ENV.local uncommitted environment-specific overrides


###> symfony/framework-bundle ###
APP_ENV=test
APP_SECRET=XXXXXXX
#TRUSTED_PROXIES=127.0.0.0/8,10.0.0.0/8,172.16.0.0/12,192.168.0.0/16
#TRUSTED_HOSTS='^(localhost|example\.com)$'
###< symfony/framework-bundle ###

###> doctrine/doctrine-bundle ###
# Format described at https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-dbal/en/latest/reference/configuration.html#connecting-using-a-url
# For an SQLite database, use: "sqlite:///%kernel.project_dir%/var/data.db"
# For a PostgreSQL database, use: "postgresql://db_user:db_password@127.0.0.1:5432/db_name?serverVersion=11&charset=utf8"
# IMPORTANT: You MUST configure your server version, either here or in config/packages/doctrine.yaml
DATABASE_URL=postgresql://root:root@postgres:5432/dbb
###< doctrine/doctrine-bundle ###

###> nelmio/cors-bundle ###
#CORS_ALLOW_ORIGIN=^https?://(localhost|127\.0\.0\.1)(:[0-9]+)?$
CORS_ALLOW_ORIGIN=^https://my-domain.com
###< nelmio/cors-bundle ###

###> lexik/jwt-authentication-bundle ###
JWT_PUBLIC_KEY=%kernel.project_dir%/config/jwt/public.pem
###< lexik/jwt-authentication-bundle ###

###> nzo/elk-bundle ###
ELK_APP_NAME=my-app
ELK_APP_ENVIRONMENT=test
###< nzo/elk-bundle ###
```

Docker file :

```
FROM php:7.4-fpm

WORKDIR /app
# Install selected extensions (git, git-flow and other stuff)
RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends zlib1g-dev libpq-dev git git-flow libicu-dev libxml2-dev libzip-dev\
    && docker-php-ext-configure intl \
    && docker-php-ext-install intl \
    && docker-php-ext-configure pgsql -with-pgsql=/usr/local/pgsql \
    && docker-php-ext-install pdo pdo_pgsql pgsql \
    && docker-php-ext-install zip xml \
    && apt-get clean; rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* /tmp/* /var/tmp/* /usr/share/doc/*

# Install composer
RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php && mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer \
    && apt-get clean; rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* /tmp/* /var/tmp/* /usr/share/doc/*

COPY ./my-project/ /usr/src/my-project
COPY docker-dist/back/config/php/php.ini /usr/local/etc/php/

COPY docker-entrypoint.sh /entrypoint.sh

RUN composer install --working-dir=/usr/src/my-project

# WORKDIR is /var/www/html (inherited via "FROM php")
# "/entrypoint.sh" will populate it at container startup from /usr/src/my-project
VOLUME /var/www/app

ENTRYPOINT ["/entrypoint.sh"]

CMD ["php-fpm"]
```

Comment: Is this `APP_ENV` overriden in all docker images or just in your staging image ?

Comment: All docker images

Comment: Did you check the env file in your containers ? Isn't it a problem with a .env.local file that's overriding the .env files of your containers ?

Comment: I did, the.env files are allright, values are OK. There's no .env.local on the clusters

Comment: And I suppose the `public/index.php` is the symfony's original one with this line `$kernel = new Kernel($_SERVER['APP_ENV'], (bool) $_SERVER['APP_DEBUG']);`

Comment: Yep That's what I have (on my pod) : ```$kernel = new Kernel($_SERVER['APP_ENV'], (bool) $_SERVER['APP_DEBUG']);```

Comment: It really seems it's nothing to do with kubernetes. How do you serve your project ? If you only have one .env file `$_SERVER['APP_ENV']` should have the value set in the .env

Comment: is it nothing to do with https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/33118 ? What's in your docker file ?

Comment: I only have one .env file on my cluster. I have a local shell script which loads the right one before the composer install. I'll add the docker file content to my post.

Comment: Somewhere in your container's configuration there is something that set $_SERVER['APP_ENV']. Check your php.ini or entrypoint.sh by exemple.

Comment: Entrypoint.sh us a good Idea ! I'm gonna it a shot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears the warmup wasn't working properly.

I had a closer look at my docker-entrypoint and manage to run composer install and cache cleaning inside.

Problem solved.

Thanks everyone.

entrypoint.sh :

````
set -e

cd /var/www/app

tar cf - --one-file-system -C /usr/src/myapp . | tar xf -

rm -rf var/cache var/log

composer install

php bin/console cache:clear --env=dev

chown -R www-data:www-data .

exec "$@"```
````